# Dockerfile CGO Confusing

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, db2, odbc

I have a golang application and I used odbc driver " https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc "  to connect mssql or mysql on Windows. I added unixodbc-dev and mssql-mysql odbc drivers to dockerfile to connect databases from a container. Normally It works. However when I add https://github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db package to connect db2 without odbc, docker build fails. Both of packages uses cgo, that's why if I don't add some lines docker build fails.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV HOME /app
ENV CGO_ENABLED 1
ENV GOOS linux
ENV TZ=Europe/Minsk
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
ENV LANG C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y


RUN curl -s https://dl.google.com/go/go1.17.linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar -v -C /usr/local -xz


ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y cifs-utils
RUN apt-get install -y w3m
RUN apt-get install -y libc6 
RUN apt-get install -y libgcrypt20
RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev
RUN apt-get install -y alien
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg
RUN apt-get update \      #ODBC
    && apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y

# mssql odbc
RUN echo "[FreeTDS]\n\
Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver\n\
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so\n\
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini

COPY ./installer/db2/setup.go ./installer/db2/setup.go # in my local folder
RUN go run ./installer/db2/setup.go
ENV DB2HOME=/home/clidriver
ENV CGO_CFLAGS=-I$DB2HOME/include #DB2 if CGO_CFLAGS and CGO_LDFLAGS set than odbc package fails.
ENV CGO_LDFLAGS=-L$DB2HOME/lib #DB2
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/clidriver/lib


WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o main .

CMD ["/app/main"]
```

If I remove odbc lines then ibm db2 package fails, If I remove DB2 lines then golang odbc package fails:

```
 => [25/26] COPY . .                                                                                                                   
11: fatal error: sqlcli1.h: No such file or directory
#30 0.671    13 | // #include <sqlcli1.h>
#30 0.671       |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
#30 0.671 compilation terminated.
```

Update:
This dockerfile does not work. If I removed these lines:

```
ENV CGO_CFLAGS=-I$DB2HOME/include #DB2 
ENV CGO_LDFLAGS=-L$DB2HOME/lib #DB2
```

Then ibm_db2 package gives error during docker build. If I don't remove anything then go odbc package gives similar error.

If I don't change anything gives this error:

```
 [33/33] RUN go build -o main .:
#39 1.585 # github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/api
#39 1.585 go/pkg/mod/github.com/alexbrainman/odbc@v0.0.0-20211220213544-9c9a2e61c5e2/api/api_unix.go:151:10: could not determine kind of name for C.SQLGUID
#39 1.585 go/pkg/mod/github.com/alexbrainman/odbc@v0.0.0-20211220213544-9c9a2e61c5e2/api/api_unix.go:133:12: could not determine kind of name for C.SQLHANDLE
#39 1.585 go/pkg/mod/github.com/alexbrainman/odbc@v0.0.0-20211220213544-9c9a2e61c5e2/api/api_unix.go:135:12: could not determine kind of name for C.SQLHDBC
#39 1.585 go/pkg/mod/github.com/alexbrainman/odbc@v0.0.0-20211220213544-9c9a2e61c5e2/api/api_unix.go:134:12: could not determine kind of name for C.SQLHENV
```

Comment: Does the Dockerfile as you've shown it work, without removing anything?  I'm a little unclear on the specific problem you're having.

Comment: If you don't change anything, what is the actual error you get?

Comment: What is your desired end goal? A dockerfile that has mssql and mysql and ibm's go_ibm_db all working together? Or something different?  Your question mabe shows a dockerfile with only unixodbc and go_ibm_db .  The IBM go_ibm_db is an odbc driver (just written in C language = clidriver) .  The error re "sqlcli1.h" missing shows that the environment variable CGO_CFLAGS did not have the correct value *at the time it was used*, maybe because you assume /home/clidriver but do not supply /home as first argument to setup.go.

Comment: Have you trying passing the exact file name of the library to the `CGO_LDFLAGS` i.e., `"-l:lib<NAME>.<a/so> -L$DB2HOME/lib"`?